# A simple spaceship game

Tags: python, beginner, game

How could I improve this code? It's a little game. If you run it, instructions will appear.

In particular, I'd like to know whether I can

1. make it considerably shorter
2. any trick :) ?
3. whether I can get rid of the repetition in 130-150.

```
import keyboard
import random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# PARAMETERS #
score = 3  # initial lives
lenght = 10  # this for the arena
width = 10

# VARIABLE DECLARATION #
runner = True
ast_x_coord = []
ast_y_coord = []


# CLASSES DECLARATION #
# it's the starship that the user moves to kill asteroids
class Spaceship:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_coord = 0

    def move_right(self):  # moves the ship to the right
        if self.x_coord <= (width - 2):
            self.x_coord += 1

    def move_left(self):  # moves the ship to the left
        if self.x_coord >= 1:
            self.x_coord -= 1


# it's the projectile emitted by the ship. it kills asterodids
class Projectile:
    def __init__(self):
        global lenght
        self.x_coord = 0
        self.y_coord = lenght
        self.stop = False  # am i moving? and do i like pizza?

    def fire(self):  # this dictates the movement of the projectile once fired
        global lenght, spaceship, runner
        self.x_coord = spaceship.x_coord
        self.y_coord = 0  # initial position
        for _i in range(lenght + 1):  # move!
            if runner and not self.stop:  # helps for "fast" shut off
                self.y_coord += 1
                sleep(0.05)
        self.stop = False  # ah you hit it!
        self.y_coord = lenght
        # so that it is back in its neutral position once fired


# i like to be killed by spaceships
class Asteroid(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # so there can be many of mee!
        self.x_coord = width
        self.y_coord = lenght - 1
        self.life = True  # am i alive? and do i like pizza?

    def go(self):  # this dictates how the asteroid moves
        global ast_x_coord, ast_y_coord, score, projectile, runner
        self.x_coord = random.randint(0, width - 1)
        self.y_coord = lenght
        for i in range(lenght + 1):
            if runner:  # so the programm shuts off rapidly
                if (self.life):
                    # so that we do not get errors once the asteroid is killed
                    self.y_coord -= 1
                    if self.y_coord == 0:
                        score -= 1  # if at the end, we lose on score
                    try:  # its coordinates may not be in the lists
                        ast_x_coord.pop(self.name)
                        ast_y_coord.pop(self.name)
                    except:
                        pass
                    finally:
                        ast_y_coord.insert(self.name, self.y_coord)
                        ast_x_coord.insert(self.name, self.x_coord)
                        # add or add back the coordinates
                    for i in range(29):
                        # 30 small delays to check often because of thread
                        if (self.y_coord == projectile.y_coord and
                            self.x_coord == projectile.x_coord
                        ):  # checks for collisions projectile - asteroid
                            ast_x_coord.pop(self.name)
                            ast_y_coord.pop(self.name)
                            # asteroid have saved them already at least once
                            ast_y_coord.insert(self.name, lenght)
                            ast_x_coord.insert(self.name, width)
                            # getting rid of the shadow remaining on screen
                            projectile.stop = (True)
                            # signaling to the projectile to stop
                            self.life = False  # you die!
                            break  # exit the loop for no delay
                        sleep(0.01)
                elif not self.life:
                    del self  # we do not want a ton of objects laying around
                    break


spaceship = Spaceship()  # the ship is being built
projectile = Projectile()  # the projectile is alive


# FUNCTIONS #
def manager():  # this manages base functions
    global score, ast_y_coord, runner
    while runner:  # so we can shut it off
        sleep(0.005)  # refresh rate
        refresh_display()
        if score <= 0:  # in case we lost
            stop()


def refresh_display():  # refreshes the frame
    global projectile, spaceship, score, lenght, width, runner
    if runner:  # so we can shut it off rapidly
        os.system('cls')  # blank paper sheet
        print('you have to kill all the asteroids')  # instructions
        print('if you fail 3 times, your game is over\n')
        print('to allign the ship with the asteroid use right/left arrow')
        print('fire with "f". if you want to quit use "q"\n')
        print('you can only fire when the past projectile has disappeared')
        print(f'>>> ONLY {int(score)} HITS LEFT <<<')  # score line
        frame = ''  # temporary variable
        for y in range(lenght):
            # we build the screen by coordinates, assigning the right item
            for x in range(width):
                try:
                    if x == ast_x_coord[ast_y_coord.index(y)]:
                        frame += ' ●'
                    elif (y, x) == (0, spaceship.x_coord):
                        frame += ' Ħ'
                    elif (y, x) == (projectile.y_coord, projectile.x_coord):
                        frame += ' ⁞'
                    elif (y-1, x) == (projectile.y_coord, projectile.x_coord):
                        frame += ' ˘'
                    else:
                        frame += '  '
                except:
                    if (y, x) == (0, spaceship.x_coord):
                        frame += ' Ħ'
                    elif (y, x) == (projectile.y_coord, projectile.x_coord):
                        frame += ' ⁞'
                    elif (y-1, x) == (projectile.y_coord, projectile.x_coord):
                        frame += ' ˘'
                    else:
                        frame += '  '
            frame += '|\n'  # so we can move to the next row
        print(frame)


def asteroid_generator():  # generates asteroid at random intervals
    id_name = 0
    global runner
    while runner:  # so everything shuts when we want
        asteroid = Asteroid(id_name)
        # new pizza-eater i.e. astroid with name 'id_name'
        ast_go = Thread(target=asteroid.go)  # its own thread of movement
        ast_go.start()
        sleep(random.uniform(1, 2.5))  # time before the next spawns
        id_name += 1  # change the name of the next


def fire():  # fires the projectile if possible
    global lenght, life
    if projectile.y_coord == lenght:
        # which means 'neutral state'. i.e not fired
        proj_fire = Thread(target=projectile.fire)  # fires the projectile
        proj_fire.start()  # in its own thread


def stop():  # ends the programm
    global runner  # shut it off
    runner = False
    os.system('cls')
    print('goodbye')


# SPACESHIP CONTROL #
keyboard.add_hotkey('right', spaceship.move_right)
keyboard.add_hotkey('left', spaceship.move_left)
keyboard.add_hotkey('f', fire)

# GAME CONTROLS #
keyboard.add_hotkey('q', stop)


# MANAGER #
# starts manager and asteroid generator
manager = Thread(target=manager)
manager.start()
sleep(5)  # you have to read instructions at the start
ast_generator = Thread(target=asteroid_generator)
ast_generator.start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
# PARAMETERS #
score = 3  # initial lives
lenght = 10  # this for the arena
width = 10
```

The names you have given to these variables are bad.

- The name `score` contradicts the comment `lives`.
- The name `length` is too broad. Length of what? It should be `arena_length` instead.
- The name `width` should be `arena_width`. I'm assuming that it is related to the arena as well.
- When the arena is displayed, it's more common to talk about width and *height* than about width and *length*, as the length does not specify any direction.

```
# VARIABLE DECLARATION #
runner = True
ast_x_coord = []
ast_y_coord = []
```

So something can be a `runner` or not. When I read this name without having any further context, I'm clueless about its intention. Maybe it's something like `game_still_running`, but at this point, I cannot know.

Instead of `ast_x_coord`, I'd rather name the variable `asteroid_x`. The `x` and `y` already suggest that these two variables form coordinates, so there is no need to repeat that in the variable name.

```
    def move_right(self):  # moves the ship to the right
        if self.x_coord <= (width - 2):
            self.x_coord += 1
```

From this code, I guess the spaceship has a width of 3. That guess was wrong though, which makes the code confusing.

A more common way to express the same thought is:

```
        if self.x + self.width + 1 <= arena_width:
            self.x += 1
```

The expression `x + width` is common for getting the right edge of an object. The `+ 1` is the planned movement to the right. If after that movement, the right edge of the spaceship is still within the arena, moving the spaceship is possible.

```
        self.stop = False  # am i moving? and do i like pizza?
```

I have no idea how a projectile is related to pizza.

Naming the variable `stop` is confusing, it contradicts the comment "am I moving". You should probably call that variable `moving` instead.

```
        self.stop = False  # ah you hit it!
```

See how confusing this is? The code says "don't stop", the comment says "you hit it", which implies that the projectile stops at this point.

```
        self.name = name  # so there can be many of mee!
```

I suppose that `mee` is a simple typo. Or is there any deeper meaning to it?

```
        self.life = True  # am i alive? and do i like pizza?
```

I'd name that variable `alive` instead of `life`.

---

I quickly read through the actual code, and it was OK. But since the variable names were so misleading, that's the one point I'm focusing on in this review. Naming things well is [one of the hard problems in computer science](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html), so it's good to practice it from the beginning.

Comment: I do really appreciate you tips. I'll try to name things better. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The manual printing and Windows-only `cls` are kind of hacky. Strongly consider using something like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) instead, which will likely run more efficiently and be more portable.

`lenght` is spelled `length`, and `astroid` `asteroid`.

None of your globals should be globals. Pass state around in parameters and return values.

Don't inherit from `(object)` in Python 3.

Add PEP484 type hints. This is especially important for function signatures like `def __init__(self, name):` where I would have guessed that `name` is a string, but should actually be hinted as `def __init__(self, name: int) -> None:`.